# Jquery regex test for exact word in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to work out how to check a string for a specific word, and if that word exists set a new variable

I have the following jQuery code:

```
val= $('#' + this_id).val();
```

val can contain different strings of words.

I know I can do :

```
if (/Approve/i.test(val)) {
    msg = "Approve"
}
```

But this also matches, Approved.. how do I match only Approve ?
Ultimately I'm look to do :

if val contains Approve msg = "Approve"

if val contains Approved msg = "Approved"

if val contains Reject msg = "Rejected"

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [word boundary (`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
if (/\bApprove\b/i.test(val)) {
    msg = "Approve";
}
```

According to [Regular expression tutorial - word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html),

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: how to apply word boundary in a dynamic variable?I have `var regEx = new RegExp(k);` which is inside a loop & k corresponds to the keys of the object.

Comment: @techie_28, `var regEx = new RegExp('\\b' + k + '\\b', 'i');` (you need to escape `k` if it contains characters that have special meaning in regular expression)

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
if (/^Approve$/i.test(val)) {
    var msg = "Approve"
}
```

`^` marks the `start`
`$` marks the `end`

```js
function check(val) {
  var msg;
  if (/^Approve$/i.test(val)) {
    msg = "Approve";
  } else if (/^Approved$/i.test(val)) {
    msg = "Approved";
  } else if (/^Reject$/i.test(val)) {
    msg = "Rejected";
  } else {
    msg = "Error";
  }
  alert(msg);
}

check("Approve");
check("Approved");
check("Reject");
check("Hello");
```

Comment: For some reason this fails for me and return msg not defined.

Comment: @JeffVader Updated my answer.

Comment: @falsetru Added an `else` block. Makes sense now.